# How Can I put span tag inside RESX file?

Tags: html, xml, resx

I have an xml file named "Strings.resx" for translation. I want to make some text highlighted I tried to put `span` something like this:

```
<span style="background: red;color: #000000;">VERDERGAAT</span>
```

and it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the exact problem you had when you tried to do this?

Comment: what is the solution you found? what is wrong with mine?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can not put "<" and ">" inside resx files

so you should simply do it like this:

```
&lt;span style='background: red;color: #000000;'&gt;VERDERGAAT&lt;/span&gt;
```

this should be ok now.

Answer (score 12):

I'm using ASP.NET 4.5 MVC 4, and with razor you can keep HTML tags in a `.resx` file like so:

```
<span style="background: red;color: #000000;">VERDERGAAT</span>
```

...and parse it correctly with `@Html.Raw(Resources.MyResourceFile.ValueName)`.

Comment: Please elaborate how to "parse it correctly with"?  I don't know where to start on this step.

Answer (score 0):

I just found another way to implement `.resx` files and html codes.

Please find it another stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45310565/1261525