# How to put HTML code into a .resx resource file?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, internationalization, resx

Strange, that no one asked this before....

I am creating templated HTML emails for 4 languages. I want to put the HTML templates into my .resx files to have easy, internationalized access to them from code. Like so:

.resx file:

```
<data name="BodyTemplate" xml:space="preserve">
    <value><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">
            <title>Title</title>
            ...
        </body>
        </html>
    </value>
</data>
```

But, obviously, the compiler complains about the HTML inside the .resx file. **Is there a way to use HTML (or XML at all) in .resx files. How?**

I am using .NET version 4 and dotLiquid as templating Engine, if that matters.

Comment: What does the comiler complain about exactly? And how do you add the HTML/XML files to your resource files?

Comment: If nobody knows how to do that you could write a "serializer" to escape the code that it is no html code anymore like < to #le# and when getting the data you could restore that to a less sign. Hope that helps if no other solution is found to this problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Suggestion: Create the file you want, name it the way you want, e.g "my_template.html"
then add this file to your project.

Click on it, then select in the properties window "Build Action" and set it to "Embedded Resource".

Whenever you want to access this file, you can use something like this (*no with proper using block*:

```
    public static string ReadTextResourceFromAssembly(string name)
    {
        using ( var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream( name ) )
        {
            return new StreamReader( stream ).ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Tailor it to your needs. The method above obtains the resource, say you have put your resource in your project `MyProject` in a subdirectory "HtmlTemplates and called it "my_template.html", then you can access it by the name 
`MyProject.HtmlTemplates.my_template.html`

You can then write it out to file or use it directly, etc.

This has some major benefits: You see your html file **in** your project, it has the html extension, so editing it in Visual Studio has syntax highlighting and all tools applied to .html files.

I have a bunch of those methods for my unit tests, this one extracts the data to a file:

```
    public static void WriteResourceToFile(string name, string destination)
    {
        using ( var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream( name ) )
        {
            if ( stream == null )
            {
                throw new ArgumentException( string.Format( "Resource '{0}' not found", name), "name" );
            }

            using ( var fs = new FileStream( destination, FileMode.Create ) )
            {
                stream.CopyTo( fs );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should also encapsule the `stream` within a `using`-block, in order for it to get disposed correctly.

Comment: @Aschratt, thanks for hinting. I missed this somehow on my first method. Fix it now.

Answer (score 7):

Put `encoded html` in the `.resx` file and then getting back the `html` using

```
@Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(...resource...));
```

Comment: I doubt this will work. Encoded HTML is still HTML (with all the angle brackets still sthere). Thus it will get me trouble still.

Answer (score 4):

This worked form me:
Put all your html code in value resource file and then retrieve it using @Html.Raw(...) like I did it here

```
 <td class="red" colspan="2" align="center">
                    <span style="color: #b01c1c;">
                        <strong>@Html.Raw(Resources.Listino.Cassette</strong>
                    </span>
 </td>
```

in the Listino resource File:
[image: Resource File]

Comment: It seems like not working. Because when you enter html code it's automatically add new string line. In your case, it is String1.

Comment: Delete the new record using standard commands

Comment: Thanks for replying back 7 years later :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a way like that:

First I created partial view in multiple languages and put the path of this partial views into `.resx` files. Next, I called `@Html.Partial()` method with the Resource string.

Please see the images below:

[image: Views]

[image: Resx file]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using Blazor (at least Server Prerendered mode, not tested with other), you can create a `MarkupString` (from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components` namespace) with the localizer value as parameter, or cast it.
The html will be rendered properly.

For example:

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<Resource> localizer

<span>@(new MarkupString(text))</span> // If assigning localizer value to a string 
<span>@((MarkupString)localizer["TextWithHtml"].Value)</span> // If using localizer value directly, need to use .Value before casting

@code {
    private string text;

    private void SetText()
    {
        text = localizer["TextWithHtml"];
    }
}
```