# How to get Resources and their names in a list?

Tags: c#, list, picturebox

This is my question's scenario:-

1. I have added a lot of images and other files(like .wav) in my Resources folder of project. The image files go with names such as "woof1", "woof2"....."env1", "env2"......"alpha1", "alpha2"..... and so on.
2. I want to access all image files starting with ONLY certain prefix (like "woof#" or "alpha#") and want to store these images in a List, and store the names of retrieved images in List.

Please help me. My project is to make a memory game..and the prefixes define different categories of images. I really need this to know.

Comment: Have you added them to the resource file in the project as well, or did you just add them to the Resources folder?

Comment: Thank you everyone for help. I followed a new approach. I created separate folders for images falling in diff. category. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the resources added to the project file as a resource? If so, you can use [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Sample code from [MSDN: Finding the Names of Resources in an Assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287526%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) :

```
System.Reflection.Assembly thisExe; 
thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string [] resources = thisExe.GetManifestResourceNames();
string list = "";

// Build the string of resources.
foreach (string resource in resources)
    list += resource + "\r\n";
```

Then after filtering the resource names to get which ones you need (e.g. using LINQ or creating a new `List` and populating it in a `foreach` loop, etc.), use [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream(v=vs.110).aspx) to actually *get* the resource.

If you *haven't* added the files to the project, I strongly recommend doing so as it means you'll have fewer files to distribute if you release it. See [MSDN: resource files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296240%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28558647/2416394

Instead of fetching the resources by name you might use

```
var list = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

to obtain the resources and run a LINQ filter on them.